# Не могу пройти на Python3 вот этот тест - test.assert_equals(dashatize(Non),"None", "Should return None")

Tags: python-3.x, массивы, алгоритм

На сайте **https://www.codewars.com/kata/58223370aef9fc03fd000071/train/python** решаю вот такое задание

***Для данного числа вернуть строку с дефисом '-' перед каждым нечетным
целым числом и после него, но не начинать и не
заканчивать строку знаком тире.***

***Я должен пройти все вот эти проверки***

```
test.describe('Basic')

test.assert_equals(dashatize(274),"2-7-4", "Should return 2-7-4")

test.assert_equals(dashatize(5311),"5-3-1-1", "Should return 5-3-1-1")

test.assert_equals(dashatize(86320),"86-3-20", "Should return 86-3-20")

test.assert_equals(dashatize(974302),"9-7-4-3-02", "Should return 9-7-4-3-02")

test.describe('Weird')


test.assert_equals(dashatize(Non),"None", "Should return None");    что такое значит в параметре функции dashatize(Non)    вот это Non


test.assert_equals(dashatize(0),"0", "Should return 0");

test.assert_equals(dashatize(-1),"1", "Should return 1");

test.assert_equals(dashatize(-28369),"28-3-6-9", "Should return 28-3-6-9");
```

**Вот моё решение:**

```
def dashatize(num=''):

    num = str(num).strip('-')
    if num == '0':
        return '0'
    elif num is None:
        return None
    string = ''
    for el in num:
        if int(el) % 2 != 0:
            string += '-'+ el + '-'
        else:
            string += el
    return string.replace('--', '-').strip('-')
```

Получаю вот такой ответ с сервера:

```
Time: 712ms Passed: 4 Failed: 0 Exit Code: 1    
Test Results:    
 Basic
      Test Passed
      Test Passed
      Test Passed
      Test Passed


STDERR
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 9, in <module>    
    test.assert_equals(dashatize(Non),"None", "Should return None");
    NameError: name 'Non' is not defined
```

***Объясните и подскажите пожалуйста, как пройти эту проверку и что это такое!!!***

Comment: Я открыл вашу ссылку и там нет `Non`. Там в "Sample Tests:" вот такая строчка `test.assert_equals(dashatize(None),"None", "Should return None");`, перезагрузите вебстраницу, пожалуйста, и попробуйте снова сдать свое решение.

Comment: только сейчас перезагрузил и опять тоже самое         test.assert_equals(dashatize(Non),"None", "Should return None");

Comment: Всё вопрос закрыт!!!  Получилась какая-то непонятка --- я своими руками приписал  test.assert_equals(dashatize(Non) к Non  символ 'e' и всё получилось и вот даже ссылка на решение  https://www.codewars.com/kata/reviews/582cc7d81558bbc42c000033/groups/5fa583fd891c350001386b5a ВСЕМ СПАСИБО!!!!